# How can i get Image URL from Firebase Storage to Firebase Database without uploading image from my app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I upload one image from my computer to Firebase Storage and now I  want that image to get in my Firebase database with his information and display it in my app. I can display information but cant display images. I google also but in every answer, they say first to upload the image to firebase storage from the app. then get his URL in the database and I don't want to upload from my app.
So if someone know then help.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Get the download link for your image Like this

```
     static final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;
String url = await storage
    .ref('YourImagePath')
    .getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: this answer is right for getting an image from storage I want to link my storage image first to my firebase database in Map Arrays and then get that to show in my app.

Comment: I think u should do that hardcoded ... U can use some method to get all the images links from firebase storage and store it in ur data base .... U will do that only one time ... because the link in const

Comment: ok I'll try thx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SARADAR21's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71814208/209103) on how to get the data for a file at a known path, you can also [list the files](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/list-files) in Cloud Storage through the API, in case you don't know the path.

From that documentation:

```
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final listResult = await storageRef.listAll();
for (var prefix in listResult.prefixes) {
  // The prefixes under storageRef.
  // You can call listAll() recursively on them.
}
for (var item in listResult.items) {
  // The items under storageRef.
}
```

You can then use the references you get this way, and call `getDownloadUrl()` to get a download URL for each of them.

Comment: Isnt it a bad practice to list all files? Because now users have access to the url's of those images which shouldnt be known to them, making the entire long unique file paths for the files uploaded useless.

Comment: If you don't want users to be able to list files, you'll have to know the path of the file(s) they *can* know about some other way, either by hardcoding it (as in SARADAR21's answer) or by get a list of the known files some other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<QuerySnapshot?> getDataFromFirebase() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Images')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot!.docs.forEach((doc) {
        List<dynamic> allImageData = doc["image_data"];
        storeImageList = allImageData.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
      });
      prefs.setStringList("imageList", storeImageList);
    });
  }
```